# Jekyll: Cannot render YAML front matter field as markdown correctly

Tags: yaml, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I am building the pages in my site with a list of nodes in the YAML front matter, like so:

```
---
title: My page
layout: default
nodes:
  - header: Node header
    text_block: >
        This is supposed to be markdown.

        [This works](http://example.com)

        But:  
        - this
        - doesn't
        - work
---
```

And then:

```
{% for node in page.nodes %}
    {{ node.text_block | markdownify }}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above example, the text_block will be rendered like this:

> This is supposed to be markdown. [This works](http://example.com) But: - this - doesn't - work

The line breaks and lists are not being rendered, it's all just put together in one big `<p>` tag.

Changing rendering engine to `redcarpet` doesn't work, and neither does adding `unindent` to the `markdownify` call

Something tells me this has to do with the indentation level, but I just can't work it out.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, it was YAML related. Instead of using `>` in the beginning of the field, I used `|`, and it solved the problem.